# Searching people on Twitter programmatically

Tags: java, twitter, social-media

I am looking for the search string that searches for people one Twitter. I looked at the following link
    https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

that elaborates on various ways to search on Twitter, but it seems like being able to search only for tweets.

Is there any twitter API that lets us search for people and their details on Twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the users/search resource help?

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/search

Joe